# How to brute force Last Pass local storage extension?

Tags: lastpass

I need to brute force Last Pass since I forgot my master password.
Anyone know how is the format of the local storage of the extension?

I was logged into it so it must have local data.
I see words.dic and LPMPMU in local storage.

Comment: did you look up Lastpass support? https://helpdesk.lastpass.com/account-recovery/

Answer (score 1):

Lastpass uses PBKDF2 for password hashing with 5000 iterations and SHA-256 [(reference)](https://helpdesk.lastpass.com/account-settings/general/password-iterations-pbkdf2/).

So if you have actually forgotten your password I doubt that you will be successful using brute force.

If you want to estimate your success probability get [hashcat](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/) and run it in benchmarking mode.
It will figure out how many hashes/second it can try and if you tell it what you are looking for (maybe you still have a vague idea what the password was)  even how many possibilities there are and how long it will take.

Comment: Can you tell me what the local storage data means? https://imgur.com/evX9N3h

Comment: I'm 99% sure I know what keywords are used in my pw but I must've made some weird iteration of it (or lastpass has a bug?). Is it possible to do a dictionary attack using my keywords?